# How to properly use base scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models that share the behavior. Both `Post` and `Comment` can have reactions.

```
# ./app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions, as: :reactionable
end

# ./app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions, as: :reactionable
end
```

When I decorate them, I end up with a lot of exact same methods.

```
# ./app/decorators/post_decorator.rb
class PostDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all

  def reactions_total_count
    object.reactions.count
  end

  def reactions_type(kind)
    object.reactions.collect(&:reaction_type).inject(0) {|counter, item| counter += item == kind ?  1 : 0}
  end

  def likes_count
    reactions_type('like')
  end

  def hearts_count
    reactions_type('heart')
  end

  def wows_count
    reactions_type('wow')
  end

  def laughs_count
    reactions_type('laugh')
  end

  def sads_count
    reactions_type('sad')
  end
end


# ./app/decorators/comment.rb
class CommentDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all

  def reactions_total_count
    object.reactions.count
  end

  def reactions_type(kind)
    object.reactions.collect(&:reaction_type).inject(0) {|counter, item| counter += item == kind ?  1 : 0}
  end

  def likes_count
    reactions_type('like')
  end

  def hearts_count
    reactions_type('heart')
  end

  def wows_count
    reactions_type('wow')
  end

  def laughs_count
    reactions_type('laugh')
  end

  def sads_count
    reactions_type('sad')
  end
end
```

I want it to look something like this, but don't know where to put the files, and exactly which technique I should use (`include` vs. `extend`).

```
# ./app/decorators/base.rb
module Base
  # methods defined here
end

# ./app/decorators/post.rb
class PostDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all
  include Base
end

# ./app/decorators/comment.rb
class CommentDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all
  include Base
end
```

Please advise. I know there is a better approach that I just can't seem to get right.

Comment: You was asking where to put your module `Base`, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know where it should go if it's included in multiple classes. Also, I'd like to know how to structure the application directory if it goes into one class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would figure out a better name for the included module. It could be treated as a *role*, using which you would enrich classes. This role would have declared a bunch of `*_count` methods that counts smth in `reactions`.
So I would name it `ReactionsCountable` and additionally put it into namespace to distinguish from the decorators: `Roles::ReactionsCountable`.

Then I would put it into:

```
/app/decorators
  /roles
    /reactions_countable.rb
  /comment.rb
  /post.rb
```

Other soulution would be to use classic inheritence. Here the `Base` name would make sense IMO:

```
class BaseDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  # declare `*_count` methods here

class PostDecorator < BaseDecorator
class CommentDecorator < BaseDecorator
```

Comment: I would prefer to use composition over inheritance. Although right now it's only counting, I anticipate there will be other reactionable things that are required.

Comment: I want to define this behavior in `/app/decorators/reactionable/base.rb`.
If `module Base` was defined here, would there be a way to `include` it into both `PostDecorator` and `CommentDecorator` is what I'm hoping to know.

Comment: `include Roles::ReactionsCountable` in both decorator classes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with Maicher's answer.

If a `CommentDecorator` is inside of `./app/decorators/comment_decorator.rb`, and we want to include a module, `ReactionablesCountable`, then we need to create a file inside of `./app/decorators/roles/reactions_countable.rb` that has module nesting which reflects the path to the file. For example, the first constant in the `include`, (`Roles`) points to the folder Rails will look for it, the second (`ReactionsCountable`), is the name of the file.

The module needs to be nested within this file as well. I've shown it below.

```
module Roles
  module ReactionsCountable
    # methods defined here.
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I meant. Sorry for not beign more precise describing it ;)